# How to check if jcrop widget (cropping area) was created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm using https://jcrop.com/ . The library has four handlers to determine if crop is activated, updated, changed or removed. I need to check when cropping widget was created. There is no event handler for that in docs. Is there a way to determine it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console.log(cropWidget)` right after you instantiate the library. It should show you the object that plugin has created. If not created, in the console you will have null/undefined.

Hope it helps you.